# Can Foodcritic lint check Berksfile?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to write a Foodcritic rule which verifies only Private Supermarkets are listed in a Berksfile.  Are the Berksfile source URLs included in the Ruby AST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you could use RuboCop. Foodcritic is only for cookbook stuffs specifically.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure this was the right forum for the question.